# Program for face recognition

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have been using the following script for face recognition as a security feature:

main.py

```
from itertools import izip
from PIL import Image
def compare(self,pic): 
    i1 = Image.open("pic1.jpg")
    i2 = Image.open(pic)
    size = i1.size
    i2 = i2.resize(size)
    assert i1.mode == i2.mode, "Different kinds of images."
    assert i1.size == i2.size, "Different sizes."

    pairs = izip(i1.getdata(), i2.getdata())
    if len(i1.getbands()) == 1:
        # for gray-scale jpegs
        dif = sum(abs(p1-p2) for p1,p2 in pairs)
    else:
        dif = sum(abs(c1-c2) for p1,p2 in pairs for c1,c2 in zip(p1,p2))
    ncomponents = i1.size[0] * i1.size[1] * 3
    print ((dif / 255.0 * 100) / ncomponents)
    return (dif / 255.0 * 100) / ncomponents

def password(self):
    import passw
    y=str(self.password_input.text)
    x=passw.verify(y)
    if x == True:
        try:
            os.startfile("recog.py")
            import time
            time.sleep(6)
            x = self.compare("security.jpg")
            if x <= 30:
                os.remove("pic1.jpg")
                os.rename("security.jpg","pic1.jpg")
                return True
            else:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError, e:
            print(e)
            sf=open('secure.txt','w')
            sf.write("")
            sf.close()
            if os.path.exists("securitylog.jpg"):
                from datetime import datetime, date, time
                dt = datetime.today()
                t=dt.strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %H:%M %p")
                t='{0:%H:%M }'.format(dt)
                f='{0:%A}, {0:%d} of {0:%B}, {0:%Y}.'.format(dt)
                timed=(("Date: ",f,"\nTime: ",t))
                timed=''.join(timed)
                sf=open('secure.txt','a')
                sf.write(timed)
                sf.close()
                kl=Thread(target=self.say, args="You are not authorized to access this program.")
                kl.start()
                p = Wrong()
                p.open()
            else:
                os.rename("security.jpg","securitylog.jpg")

    else:
        sf=open('secure.txt','w')
        sf.write("")
        sf.close()
        if os.path.exists("securitylog.jpg"):
            from datetime import datetime, date, time
            dt = datetime.today()
            t=dt.strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %H:%M %p")
            t='{0:%H:%M }'.format(dt)
            f='{0:%A}, {0:%d} of {0:%B}, {0:%Y}.'.format(dt)
            timed=(("Date: ",f,"\nTime: ",t))
            timed=''.join(timed)
            sf=open('secure.txt','a')
            sf.write(timed)
            sf.close()
            kl=Thread(target=self.say, args="You are not authorized to access this program.")
            kl.start()
            p = Wrong()
            p.open()
        else:
            os.rename("security.jpg","securitylog.jpg")
```

passw.py:

```
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
import onetimepad
def verify(string):
        y=string
        key=y[-2:]
        enc=onetimepad.encrypt(y,key)
        x=sha256_crypt.verify(enc,'<hash>')
        return x
def main():
        x=raw_input("Enter Password: ")
        print verify(x)

if __name__ =="__main__":
        main()
```

recog.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Python 2/3 compatibility
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import numpy as np
import cv2
# local modules
from video import create_capture
from common import clock, draw_str


def detect(img, cascade):
    rects = cascade.detectMultiScale(img, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=4, minSize=(30, 30),
                                     flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
    if len(rects) == 0:
        return []
    rects[:,2:] += rects[:,:2]
    return rects

def draw_rects(img, rects, color):
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in rects:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), color, 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys, getopt
    print("Face Recognition using Haar Cascades")

    args, video_src = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], '', ['cascade=', 'nested-cascade='])
    try:
        video_src = video_src[0]
    except:
        video_src = 0
    args = dict(args)
    cascade_fn = args.get('--cascade', "E:\\Python27\\My programs\\opencv\\sources\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")
    nested_fn  = args.get('--nested-cascade', "E:\\Python27\\My programs\\opencv\\sources\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_eye.xml")

    cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascade_fn)
    nested = cv2.CascadeClassifier(nested_fn)

    cam = create_capture(video_src, fallback='synth:bg=../data/lena.jpg:noise=0.05')

    while True:
        ret, img = cam.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)

        t = clock()
        rects = detect(gray, cascade)
        vis = img.copy()
        draw_rects(vis, rects, (0, 255, 0))
        if not nested.empty():
            for x1, y1, x2, y2 in rects:
                roi = gray[y1:y2, x1:x2]
                vis_roi = vis[y1:y2, x1:x2]
                subrects = detect(roi.copy(), nested)
                print("Face detected")
                image = vis_roi
                cv2.imwrite('security.jpg', image)
                cv2.destroyWindow('facedetect')
                sys.exit()
        dt = clock() - t

        draw_str(vis, (20, 20), 'time: %.1f ms' % (dt*1000))
        cv2.imshow('facedetect', vis)

        if 0xFF & cv2.waitKey(5) == 27:
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

As you can see i have provide all the code to ensure that my face recognition program works.

I feel that the above code is not very efficient. Is there a better way to use face recognition as a security measure using python?

Comment: Hi, asked question about your question [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/136020/84365), you might be interested :)

Comment: Please also read up on Intel 3D secure and Windows Hello, which enables this for the web, and Windows 10 devices. http://security.stackexchange.com/q/136161/396

Comment: @MatthewRock I know that I'm replying really late, but that is in fact an amazing question. Personally, I still feel that it is a vaild security feature. Now that even Apple has FaceID, I guess my point still holds good

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should read and follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
This means:

- Put all imports at the top of the file.
- Put a space around assignment operators.
- Place a space after most commas.
- Use descriptive names.

This is as it makes your code *much* easier to read.
We put spaces around words in English to increase readability,
we do it in programming languages to do the same.

---

You should:

- Use `with`.
  This makes sure the file is closed, even if the program errors. Say the user force quits the program, `KeyboardInterrupt`.
- Don't use `assert`.
  `assert` is for debugging, not for live code.
  If I run your code with the `-O` flag, it removes all of these, and then your code is broken.
- Allow more customizability.
  Passing to functions a couple of file names is not hard.
  What's more hard is when you decide to change `pic1.jpg` to `image.jpg` *and* also use `pic1.jpeg`.
  This means you'll need to re-write your code to allow you to do this.
- Don't have massive `try` blocks.
  This can lead to masking of bugs.
  This is as you may have two functions that raise say `ValueError`s.
  But you don't know which one raised `ValueError`, and now you're handling unknown states.
- Again put *all* imports at the top of you files.
  This allows me to know what you are importing as soon as I open your file.
  This prevents confusion, like you did in `main.py` where you never import `os`, but you're using it.
- Remove duplicated code.
  You need to put duplicated code in a new function or re-arrange your current one to be able to merge the duplicated code.
  Take `password` in `main.py`, you duplicated a large chunk of the function where you can join it together, or at least make a function for it.

The biggest changes I know how to make are to `main.py`. Other than the above, I changed your code to use less variables, and removed dead code.
Take:

```
dt = datetime.today()
t=dt.strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %H:%M %p")
t='{0:%H:%M }'.format(dt)
f='{0:%A}, {0:%d} of {0:%B}, {0:%Y}.'.format(dt)
timed=(("Date: ",f,"\nTime: ",t))
timed=''.join(timed)
```

The first `t` is dead code, you instantly overwrite `t` to something else, so you can remove it.
After this you have the two `timed` variables, you can change this to a single `str.format`, `Date: {}\nTime: {}`.
From this you should notice you can merge all the `str.format`s into one, and end up with:

```
timed = 'Date: {0:%A}, {0:%d} of {0:%B}, {0:%Y}.\nTime: {0:%H:%M }'.format(datetime.today())
```

I'll only show the changes to `main.py`, as the other files didn't have as much to change:

```
from itertools import izip
import time
from datetime import datetime, date, time

from PIL import Image

import passw


def compare(self, picture1, picture2): 
    image1 = Image.open(picture1)
    image2 = Image.open(picture2).resize(image1.size)
    if image1.mode != image2.mode:
        raise ValueError("Different kinds of images.")
    if image1.size != image2.size:
        raise ValueError("Different sizes.")

    pairs = izip(image1.getdata(), image2.getdata())
    if len(image1.getbands()) == 1:
        dif = sum(abs(p1-p2) for p1, p2 in pairs)
    else:
        dif = sum(abs(c1-c2) for p1, p2 in pairs for c1, c2 in zip(p1,p2))

    ret = (dif / 255.0 * 100) / image1.size[0] * image1.size[1] * 3
    print ret
    return ret


def password(self):
    y = str(self.password_input.text)
    x = passw.verify(y)
    if x:
        try:
            os.startfile("recog.py")
            time.sleep(6)
            if self.compare("pic1.jpg", "security.jpg") <= 30:
                os.remove("pic1.jpg")
                os.rename("security.jpg", "pic1.jpg")
                return True
            else:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError, e:
            print(e)

    # If not x or ValueError.
    with open('secure.txt', 'w') as sf:
        sf.write('')
    if os.path.exists("securitylog.jpg"):
        with open('secure.txt', 'a') as sf:
            sf.write('Date: {0:%A}, {0:%d} of {0:%B}, {0:%Y}.\nTime: {0:%H:%M }'
                     .format(datetime.today()))
        kl = Thread(target=self.say, args="You are not authorized to access this program.")
        kl.start()
        p = Wrong()
        p.open()
    else:
        os.rename("security.jpg", "securitylog.jpg")
```